# Promethesus: How do I write a PromQL query to find the drastic increase or decrease by some X% in my graph and stays for 10m, need to raise an alert

Tags: prometheus, promql, prometheus-alertmanager, grafana-alerts, sre

I am trying to use rate() query like comparing last 10 min with the previous 50 min like:

(sum by() rate(cmd_get{}[10m]) / (sum by() rate(cmd_get{}[50m] offset 10m))

If I want to check the percentage increase is more than 50% then what is the constant_value I can compare the above query with?
query > constant_value

or if I want to find to decrease by 50% or more I should give < constant_value

or how can I see the percentage change, what would be the query used for that

Answer (score 1):

Try the following query:

```
(sum rate(cmd_get[10m]) / sum rate(cmd_get[50m] offset 10m)) > 0.5 < 1.5
```

See the live example [here](http://demo.robustperception.io:9090/graph?g0.expr=(sum(rate(prometheus_http_requests_total%5B5m%5D))%20%2F%20sum(rate(prometheus_http_requests_total%5B5m%5D%20offset%201d)))%20%3E%200.5%20%3C%201.5&g0.tab=0&g0.stacked=0&g0.range_input=1h).